# HttpHandler to redirect url in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httphandler

I'm trying to write an HttpHandler that does url redirection ,

For example,  every time I write the url : www.google.com

It redirects to www.yahoo.com

How can I do that ?

What defines  do I need to change is IIS (7.0)

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I use this with IIS 5 and 6 - http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the IIS [url rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)?